# Geting the file object from a form in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a scenario where I have to make use of a form the old fashioned why like this;

```
<form action="{{ path('admin_app_address_import') }}" method="post" name="form_import">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="inputFile" accept="text/csv" name="inputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Select a CSV file to import.</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then get the parameters from the form like this inside my action;

```
public function importAction(Request $request) {   
    $file = $request->files->get('inputFile');
    var_dump($file);exit;
    //...
}
```

But I keep on getting null. How can I get the file I try to read from? I don't need to store it in a database whatsoever, I just need to read the content to upload that to the database. I'm making a CSV import action, but I can't seem to get the file object.

When doing `var_dump($request->request->all());` I do get the filename, but that won't work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When allowing file uploads, the encoding type of the form must be set to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of that, but I completely forgot about that. It did the trick for me.